# How can I change a List Calendar time intervals to 15 minutes?

Tags: calendar

I have a list for booking product moves with a factory assigned to specific material handling eqiupment, and would like to show the booking in a calendar view. The only problem I have is that a move booked for 08:20 is shown along side a move booked for 08:30 due to the calendar time intervals being 30 minutes. Is there a way to change this so the booking are shown sequentially?